# What happened to Boba in between Attack of the Clones and The Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, attack-of-the-clones, boba-fett

In *Attack of the Clones*, after Jango is killed, Boba goes down to the battlefield to find his father's helmet.  In season 2 of *The Clone Wars*, which takes place about a year after AotC, Boba is running with Aurra Sing and acting as a bounty hunter.

My question is: what exactly happened in this in-between period?  Is there maybe a book that covers him after Jango's death?  Do we know exactly how long it was between then and when Aurra took him in?

Comment: So you might say you’re looking for a book of Boba Fett(‘s early life as an orphan).

Comment: Wookieepedia just says "*Sometime later*"; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett#Clone_Wars. I assume we're expected to understand that he was fending for himself during this period, possibly collecting holdout supplies left by his father and generally plotting against Windu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Legends

This was the subject of the [*Boba Fett* series of young reader novels](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett_(books)), published between 2002 and 2004. Their placement in the timeline relative to *The Clone Wars* is a little murky, since TCW established a new version of the events of the Clone Wars compared to pre-2008 Legends media. However, the works themselves were never decanonized, and [*The Essential Reader's Companion*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Reader%27s_Companion) gives an updated ordering (summaries paraphrased):

#### Boba Fett #1: The Fight to Survive (22 BBY)

After the events of *Attack of the Clones*, Boba is left instructions by Jango to find Darth Tyranus so that he can recover Jango's funds. Aurra Sing captures him and brings him to Count Dooku on Raxus Prime, who Boba doesn't yet realize is the same person as Tyranus.

#### Boba Fett #2: Crossfire (22 BBY)

The Republic attacks Raxus Prime, separating Boba from Dooku, and he is taken to Bespin by the clones, who think he's a war orphan. Aurra Sing is after Jango's funds as well, and Boba and Aurra end up leaving Bespin on Slave I.

#### Boba Fett #3: Maze of Deception (22 BBY)

Boba and Aurra team up to recover Jango's funds from the banking planet Aargau. Boba ends up escaping with the money, but loses some of it to a con artist. He ends up escaping by himself aboard Slave I.

#### Boba Fett #4: Hunted (22 BBY)

This one is placed after the TCW novelization, but still before Season 2. Boba starts working as a bounty hunter for Jabba the Hutt on Tatooine, and hunts down the Neimoidian Gilramos Libkath.

The other two books in the series, *A New Threat* and *Pursuit*, were intended to take place closer to Episode III, and take place in 19 BBY under the updated placement.

## Canon

Currently, there don't seem to be any Canon works featuring Boba that are set between *Attack of the Clones* and [*The Clone Wars* S2E10: Death Trap](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Trap). This is reflected in [*Ultimate Star Wars* (2019)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars,_New_Edition): the only event between "Death of Jango" and the events of Death Trap is this:

> **Becoming a Hunter**
>
> Boba joins Bossk, Aurra Sing, and others to learn the tricks of the bounty hunting trade.
>
> <sub>*Ultimate Star Wars* (2019), page 55: Boba Fett</sub>